# Announce a members role ADDED to a specific role in a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'd like to have my bot announce in our specific channel called family-talk, which I do have the channel ID of as well but not sure where to put it, but I'd want this to only happen when a role has been added to a member, is my below code correct or wrong? I don't have a lot of good ways of testing this so i'm hoping for some big help here. I also would like to know where the best place would be to place the code. Thank you!

```
   if(!oldMember.roles.has('539208166563643407') && newMember.roles.has('561773668439687179'))
   client.channels.get("550197572178935809").send("This member got the special role!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, BUT you have 2 diffrent IDs in the if, so to make this a bit cleaner just do:

```
const roleID = '539208166563643407';
const channelID = '550197572178935809';

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(!oldMember.roles.has(roleID) && newMember.roles.has(roleID)) {
        client.channels.get(channelID).send(newMember.displayName + ' got the special role!');
    }
});
```